# How to open port 990 on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw, apparmor

I am not able to connect to my server using FTPS. I noticed that port 990 is not open. When I try to connect to my server on port number 990  I get the following:

```
telnet myip 990
Connecting To myip...Could not open connection to the host, on port 990: Connect failed
```

I am able to telnet to the same server on port 21.

How can I open port 990 on my ubuntu server?

The firewall is inactive:

```
ubuntu@ip: sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

This is what I get for iptables:

```
ubuntu@ip:sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This is what I get from apparmor:

```
ubuntu@ip: sudo aa-status
apparmor module is loaded.
22 profiles are loaded.
20 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /snap/core/11993/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/11993/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/lxc-start
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   lxc-container-default
   lxc-container-default-cgns
   lxc-container-default-with-mounting
   lxc-container-default-with-nesting
   man_filter
   man_groff
   snap-update-ns.amazon-ssm-agent
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap.core.hook.configure
2 profiles are in complain mode.
   snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent
   snap.amazon-ssm-agent.ssm-cli
2 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
2 processes are in complain mode.
   snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent (814)
   snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent (1034)
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

The server is an EC2 instance, I also have defined the following rules in the security group:
[image]

Comment: Your output suggests that the firewall is not preventing connections. Check that your desired application is actually active and listening on that port. `sudo ss -tulpn` is a handy tool for such checking.

Comment: @user535733: you are right. I tried changing the VSFTP to listen to port 990 and then the telnet was successfull.